# Want implement cache in web role in azure emulator 1.8 for local and deployment

Tags: azure

Want implement cache in web role cache in azure emulator 1.8 for local and deployment.

I try many codes but not working

web.config file settings

I am testing this code on visual studio 2012 with azure emulator 1.8 version.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <!-- Append below entry to configSections. Do not overwrite the full section. -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="dataCacheClients" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientsSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
  </configSections>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebRole1-20130503143610;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebRole1-20130503143610.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
    </authentication>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
  <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider" timeout="30">
    <providers>
        <add name="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider" 
             type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheSessionStoreProvider, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
             cacheName="default"/>
    </providers>
</sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="default">
      <hosts>
        <host name="localhost" cachePort="22233" />
      </hosts>

      <!--<securityProperties mode="Message">
        <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="e58a8dbc-5093-4124-b5fd-9b9538d72213"></messageSecurity>
      </securityProperties>-->
    </dataCacheClient>

  </dataCacheClients>
</configuration>
------------------------------------------------------------------

Coding for test cache

public partial class _Default : Page
    {
          DataCacheFactory myFactory;
          DataCache myCache;
          Random randomizer = new Random();


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                     myFactory = new DataCacheFactory();
                    myCache = myFactory.GetDefaultCache();
                    string Test = "Test1";
                    myCache.Put("MyKey", Test);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more detail as to what you are attempting to do and what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading [About Windows Azure Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914161.aspx) then read [Windows Azure Caching on Existing Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914128.aspx).  There are links to samples and plenty of code examples in the documentation.  Your config is for a cache that doesn't exist - cachePort="22233" is for the old Azure Fabric Shared Cache and can't be used with localhost.